# How to convert user upload images to webp in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-processing, imagemagick, carrierwave, webp

I want to convert user uploading images in `webp` for site performance. I know `webp` now support only on two browsers, `Google Chrome` and `Opera`.

I am using `carrierwave` for image uploading to `s3`.

Not find any support of  converting image to `webp` in `carrierwave`.

`image-magick` have libraries `libwebp` which can convert images to `webp`.

Is there any gem of that in rails?

How I can convert image to `carrierwave` and save it also.
Solution other than `carrierwave` also works.

Comment: Perhaps RMagick at https://github.com/rmagick-temp/rmagick along with the webp delegate library at https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/download

Comment: but is there any support of it in carrierwave?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know Carrierwave nor how it utilizes Imagemagick.

Comment: @WaqasAhad did you get anywhere with it?

Comment: @ChrisEdwards not yet...if you find update me also please

Answer (score 8):

I had similar task but without uploading to S3.
I used [webp-ffi](https://github.com/le0pard/webp-ffi) gem to write custom converter.

This is my solution that helped me.

First you need to install [requirements](https://github.com/le0pard/webp-ffi#requirements) specified in README file of [webp-ffi](https://github.com/le0pard/webp-ffi) gem.

After that add [webp-ffi](https://github.com/le0pard/webp-ffi) gem to your project:

```rb
gem 'webp-ffi'
```

If you don't need to store original images you can just add custom method to your uploader and call it with process method of CarrierWave. Here is my hack for converting images to webp format:

```rb
class MyImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :file

  process convert_to_webp: [{ quality: 80, method: 5 }]

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  private

  def convert_to_webp(options = {})
    # Build path for new file
    webp_path = "#{path}.webp"

    # Encode (convert) image to webp format with passed options
    WebP.encode(path, webp_path, options)

    # HACK: Changing of this two instance variables is the only way 
    #   I found to make CarrierWave save new file that was created 
    #   by encoding original image.
    @filename = webp_path.split('/').pop

    @file = CarrierWave::SanitizedFile.new(
      tempfile: webp_path,
      filename: webp_path,
      content_type: 'image/webp'
    )
  end
end
```

You can move this method to some module located in your project (make sure it will [autoload](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html) correctly). For example I put this code in `app/services/web_p_converter.rb`:

```rb
module WebPConverter
  def convert_to_webp(options = {})
    webp_path = "#{path}.webp"

    WebP.encode(path, webp_path, options)

    @filename = webp_path.split('/').pop

    @file = CarrierWave::SanitizedFile.new(
      tempfile: webp_path,
      filename: webp_path,
      content_type: 'image/webp'
    )
  end
end
```

Now I can include this module in every uploader that needs webp conversion:

```rb
class MyImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include WebPConverter

  storage :file

  process convert_to_webp: [{ quality: 80, method: 5 }]

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end
```

But if you need to store original version of file and create a version inside uploader you will need to use this hack:

```rb
class MyImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include WebPConverter

  storage :file

  version :webp do
    process convert_to_webp: [{ quality: 80, method: 5 }]

    def full_filename(file)
      return "#{version_name}_#{filename}" if filename.split('.').last == 'webp'

      "#{version_name}_#{file}.webp"
    end
  end

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end
```

This has to be done because CarrierWave uses original image name to build paths to other versions.

Also you can move logic from #full_filename into a method. For example I moved the logic of building full filename into WebPConverter module so it look something like this:

```rb
module WebPConverter
  # ...

  def build_webp_full_filename(filename, version_name)
    return "#{version_name}_#{filename}" if filename.split('.').last == 'webp'

    "#{version_name}_#{filename}.webp"
  end
end
```

And from now I can use it for my versions that needs conversion to webp:

```rb
class MyImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include WebPConverter

  storage :file

  version :webp do
    process convert_to_webp: [{ quality: 80, method: 5 }]

    def full_filename(file)
      build_webp_full_filename(file, version_name)
    end
  end

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end
```

Checkout [carrierwave-webp](https://github.com/kavu/carrierwave-webp) gem that I used as example to create my solution to this problem (this gem did not worked for me for some reason).

Also checkout my [simple app](https://github.com/pshnn/rails_carrierwave_webp_example) that I made to demonstrate working solution.

Comment: Excellent solution but it doesn't remove the image.

Comment: Nope. The webp image. I had to clean this up with a separate callback method.

Answer (score 0):

```
module WebPConverter
  private

  def build_webp_full_filename(filename, version_name)
    return "#{version_name}_#{filename}" if filename.split('.').last == 'webp'

    "#{version_name}_#{filename}.webp"
  end
end
```

and in ImageUploader

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  include CarrierWave::WebP::Converter
  include WebPConverter

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  version :thumb do
    process resize_to_fit: [50, 50]
  end
  
  version :img_quality do
    process resize_to_fit: [600, 600]
    process quality: 60
  end

  version :webp do
    process convert_to_webp: [{ quality: 60, method: 5 }]
    process resize_to_fit: [600, 600]
    def full_filename(file)
      build_webp_full_filename(file, version_name)
    end
  end

  def extension_whitelist
    %w[jpg jpeg gif png]
  end
end
```

and providing different formats depending on the browser
gem 'browser'

in views:

```
<%= image_tag set_browser(deals_first(@category).brand.logo) %>
```

helper

```
 def set_browser(object)
    browser.chrome? || browser.opera? || browser.platform.android? ? 
    object.webp.url : object.quality.url
  end
```